# Premium Tier is disabled in this workspace. Secret scopes can only be created with initial_manage_principal "users"

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-databricks, azure-aks

While creating the secret scope for key-vault, I am getting this error. I am using free trail of Microsoft Azure for 1 month. I can see a verification error on the top of the screen. Why I am getting this error and what is the solution?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the error? where are you getting this error? in Key vault or in Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

> Premium Tier is disabled in this workspace. Secret scopes can only be created with initial_manage_principal "users"

[image]

When attempting to build a secret scope, the Azure Databricks service should have been configured with the Premium Pricing Tier; otherwise, the aforementioned verification error will be displayed.

Therefore, the Pricing Tier would need to be modified from the default Standard to premium during the establishment of the service:

[image]